# Start terminal when a function is called in Python

Tags: python, function, terminal

My Python program runs in the background. I need to open a terminal when a specific function is called and print on this terminal. How to do it?

For example:

```
def example_function():
    <exit from the background and open a terminal>
    print("Something")
    <exit from the function, terminal might stay there>
```

Example view of the terminal:

```
Something
[user@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this with a terminal? Why not use something like Tkinter that allows you to open regular windows?

Comment: You can use `subprocess.run('/bin/bash')`.

Comment: @TimRoberts That won't open a terminal, it will run in the current terminal window. You need to run something like `gnome-terminal` or `xterm`.

Comment: Also, background processes can't read from the terminal by default.

Comment: Yes.  I am reading between the lines.  From his example, he doesn't want a terminal.  He wants a shell.  I might be misreading it.

Comment: @Barmar My program listens to directories in the background with `watchdog` and when a change within the directory occurs it starts to back up the directory. I want this backup process visible.

Comment: Then you probably want something like `xterm -e 'backup_command'`

Comment: @Barmar It should be distribution independent. I need the display on the distribution's terminal.

Comment: I've been googling and I can't find a library for opening terminal windows in an OS/distro-independent way.

Comment: `xterm` should be nearly universal.  It goes back 40 years to the very beginnings of the X system.  However, if you just want to DISPLAY the progress, then just create a window, launch a subprocess and capture its stdout into your window.  I've done that many times.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "distribution's terminal." Even assuming you're talking only about Linux distros (and thus excluding macOS, Solaris, Windows, etc.) there are many terminals available to the user. Just about the only thing you can safely assume is that `xterm` is available. Also, unless you need the user to be able to interact with the process you launch inside the terminal you don't really need a terminal. As Barmar pointed out it is simpler and more portable to simply capture the output of the backup program and display it in a Tkinter message box.